# How to append json objects below exixting data in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

as html page

```
 <div class="posts" ng-repeat="s in news" ng-init="moreNews()">
      {{s.news}}
 </div>
 <input type="button" value="get data" onclick="moreNews()"/>
```

at controller

```
$scope.moreNews = function () {
       $http.get("test?p=" + $scope.pno)
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $scope.news = response.data.news;
                    $scope.pno++;
                  }, function (data) {
                    alert("Oops! Unable to get data from server")
                });
    };
```

Here I am getting data from server and showing to html page. Here first response is showin data properly. but for second response it is overriding the data I want to add next data to below the first one and so one.

How to append lists below the existing data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$scope.moreNews = function () {
       $http.get("test?p=" + $scope.pno)
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    for(var i=0;i<response.data.news.length;i++){
                      $scope.news.push(response.data.news[i]);
                    }                    
                    $scope.pno++;
                  }, function (data) {
                    alert("Oops! Unable to get data from server")
                });
    };
```

Comment: Declare $scope.news = []; on page load

Comment: response.data.news.forEach(x=> $scope.news.push(x));
 make it even shorter instead of for loop, cheers

Answer (score 2):

Try out this code

```
$scope.moreNews = function () {
       $http.get("test?p=" + $scope.pno)
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $scope.news=$scope.news.concat(response.data.news);
                    $scope.pno++;
                  }, function (data) {
                    alert("Oops! Unable to get data from server")
                });
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.news = [];

$scope.moreNews = function () {
   $http.get("test?p=" + $scope.pno)
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.news.push(response.data.news);
                $scope.pno++;
              }, function (data) {
                alert("Oops! Unable to get data from server")
            });
};
```

The **push()** method 
 - Adds one or more elements to the end of the same array.